# how to setup my htaccess to redirect several sub-folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have one domain: **example.com**

On this domain I have two different websites: **example.com/site1** and **example.com/site2**

How can i set my htaccess to:

- redirect ALL the http version on https
- redirect ALL the www version to a non www version

Do I need to create 2 different htaccess in each folder (**example.com/site1** and **example.com/site2**) or only one in the root folder (**example.com**) ?